# MS CRM 2011 forms: "visible by default" Field Property checkbox is not working

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I recently migrated a crm 4 database to crm 2011. We are using the on premise version.

I am now adapting scripts and forms to crm 2011. With one of my forms I have the following issue: I am trying to hide the owner from the form.

To do this I have unchecked the "Visible by default" check box on the Field Properties form.

This works on most forms, but on one of the forms the owner is displayed no matter what I do. I've been able to move the field around in the form, remove the label etc. All this works, but  changes to the visibility will not work.

Has anybody seen this? Why is it not working? Does anybody have an idea on how to fix the issue without writing custom javascript (this probably would work, but I'm interested in getting the "Visible by default" checkbox to work again.

### Update

The custom entity only has a single form defined.
There is no custom javascript on this form but I checked for javascript errors anyway and there were none. Even more strange, if I look at the html code I see
the following code if the check box is NOT ticked (style visiblity set to visible!):

```
<td class="ms-crm-FieldLabel-LeftAlign ms-crm-Field-Required" id="ownerid_c" style="visibility: visible;">
```

whereas is the checkbox IS ticked I will get (no style attribute at all!):

```
<td class="ms-crm-FieldLabel-LeftAlign ms-crm-Field-Required" id="ownerid_c">
```

needless to say that I did publish my changes.

On a form where the check box is working as expected I see the following html (style attribute display set to none):

```
<td class="ms-crm-FieldLabel-LeftAlign ms-crm-Field-Required" id="ownerid_c" style="display: none;">
```

### Update 2

This issue is happening in the update form of the entity (so the owner is not null).
I moved the owner to a section and tried hiding the section, but unfortunately the section
will not hide. **But* if I move the owner out of the section, the section will hide. I wonder what this owner field has, that won't let me hide it.

Comment: Which entity/form? Custom or system?

Comment: this is a custom entity

Answer (score 1):

This plagued me for ages until I realized what was going on.  I was trying to make an update form completely readonly.  The CRM form requires at least one readable field on an update form.  When it doesn't find one, it leaves one visible and readable (normally the owner or name field or whatever happens to be the last field on the form).  I found the following javascript code somewhere and it works well to disable all the fields on the form without showing the pesky owner field that you have set not visible by default. (Props to the author as I don't remember where I got it)

```
function DisableFormFields() {
    Xrm.Page.ui.controls.forEach(function(control, index) {
        if (doesControlHaveAttribute(control)) {
            control.setDisabled(true);
        }
    });
}

function doesControlHaveAttribute(control) {
    var controlType = control.getControlType();
    return controlType != "iframe" && controlType != "webresource" && controlType != "subgrid";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because this is such a basic part of forms in CRM, I'm going to guess that your true problem is something else that results in the field not getting hidden.  If you push `F12` in IE, and go to the script tab to debug, do you see any javascript errors?

Also ensure you're looking at the correct from.  In CRM 2011, you can have different forms for different roles, so be sure to check the forms drop down on the upper left.

And don't forget to publish your customizations!

### Edit

I do know that if a field is marked as required, it will display it anyway if you attempt to save the form and it is null.  Is this happening on a create of the entity, or an update of the entity with the value already populated?

I'd try moving the field to it's own section, and making the whole section not visible.  This is also a good practice because if you add additional fields to the form, the hidden ones will take up space in the form.

Comment: <td class="ms-crm-FieldLabel-LeftAlign ms-crm-Field-Required" id="ownerid_c" style="visibility: visible;">

Comment: Ok, so you can ignore any javascript issues.  Have you double checked you're testing in the right environment/form, and that you have completely published your customizations?

Comment: SO would prefer that if you'r going to include additional detail to your question like what you have in the comment, that you edit your answer with the additional detail.

Comment: I added my comment to the problem description above.

Comment: added results of trying to move the field to a section above.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the RTM version of CRM 2011? there is a known bug that has been fixed with rollup 1

> You cannot set field visibility to "true" through the Client API when the Visible by Default field is not selected.

maybe your problem is related/connected to this bug

you can read the changelog here:

[Update Rollup 1 for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 is available](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2466084/en-us)